# how can I overcome with this dependency issue which is for crop the image?

Tags: android

'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'

I add this dependency in my app after adding this dependency i get an compilation error in android studio.

This is the error:

```
Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$1
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$1, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

I put a [link](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) of source files of this dependency.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCCfC.png)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.pranav.friendsadda"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.0'
//noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Show the whole gradle file, where you have all dependencies declared.

Comment: I add my gradle file, you can check now.